# Meaning of как + time elapsed

Tags: словоупотребление, глаголы, наречия

I don't understand the function of **как** in this sentence:

> Возле окна — большая клетка Букли. Сейчас она пустая: Букля уже два
>   дня как улетела.

I know there a usage of **как** with perfective verbs that means "suddenly." However I wonder if here it isn't "approximating" two days: ***about* two days ago.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unrelated to the *как* that expresses suddenness. And approximating two days would be an entirely different construction: *Букля улетела **дня два** назад.*

In phrases like this one, *как* serves to further stress that the time elapsed is the focus/"rheme"/new information communicated by the sentence.

Comment: Very useful, and impeccable English! Please look over my other questions and see if you have anything to add. :)

Comment: Also, along with the use of как here to emphasize the time elapsed, is there also an added intonational emphasis on два дня?

Comment: Can this be explained by hypothesizing a contraction of *Прошло два дня с тех пор (с того момента), как (когда) Букля улетела*?

Answer (score 7):

This **как** refers to **уже два дня**, not to the verb.

**[Вот] уже** *period of time* **как** means 'it's already been *period of time* since', and "Букля уже два дня как улетела" means 'it's been already two days since Buklya flew away.'

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain colloquial trend where conjunction *как* replaces *когда*. E.g.

***Как*** *дойдёте до перекрёстка, поверните налево*

(I think I can see a direct analogy in English: ***When*** *you reach the junction turn left* => ***As*** *you reach the junction turn left* - is it a contraction of *as soon as*?)

I am not sure as to the reasons for this phenomenon but the following excerpt from Lermontov's well-known pastiche indicates that some historical process may be at work here:

```
Как сходилися, собиралися
Удалые бойцы московские
На Москву-реку, на кулачной бой,
Разгуляться для праздника, потешиться.
```

So I am tempted to hypothesize a transformation:

*Прошло <уже>* [a period of time] *с тех пор (с того момента) как (когда)* [the event happened] => <уже> [a period of time] *как* [the event happened] => [the event] <уже> [a period of time] *как* [happened].

I would also argue that this usage does preserve a certain shade of suddenness or rather    instantaneousness of the event or the particular moment. One would say *Как вошёл я в ресторан, сразу увидел Сашу*, but never *Как жил я Москве, каждый день ходил в Большой*. Only *когда* will be used in the latter case. The escape of a bird lends itself very well to such suddenness.

It is also worth adding that *с тех пор как* is a stable and actively used idiom.

Comment: Very interesting hypothesis. Thanks for the clarification :)